# Histogram on the basis of facet counts

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram

I am currently working on a project in which I am storing user activity logs in elasticsearch. the user field in the log is like {"user":"abc@yahoo.com"}. I have a timestamp field for each activity, that describes when this activity was recorded. Can i generate date histogram on the basis of number of users in a particular time period. eg the histogram entry must show the number of users on that time. I can have this implemented by obtaining facet counts, but i need to get counts on various intervals and various ranges with minimum queries. Please guide me in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: there is a tutorial on this on the elastisearch website http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/histogram-facet/

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/facets/

Comment: there is also a plugin for elastisearch that will do this available at github https://github.com/ptdavteam/elasticsearch-approx-plugin

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) Can you post what your data looks like, at least for what concerns the field that you mentioned for your facet?

Answer (score 1):

Add a facet to your query something like the following:

```
{"facets": {
  "daily_volume": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "size": 100,
      "field": "created_at",
      "interval": "day"
      "order": "time"
     }
   }
 }
```

This returns a nice set of ordered data for the number of items per day.

I then feed this to a Google Chart (the ColumnChart works nicely for histograms), doing a conversion on the returned timestamp integer to convert it to a Date type understood correctly by the Javascript charts API.